# Create a relationship between two custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have `Photographer` and `Gear` custom post types. I want to be able to relate multiple 'gear' posts under a 'photographer' and then also be able to point to the related 'photographers' under a gear page.

Here's an example diagram I created: [image]

Answer (score 3):

WordPress by itself doesn't provide a built-in way to handle `many-to-many` relationships, you have two general ways of creating such relationship:

1. **Using a plugin**

   The best plugin for this purpose is [`Posts 2 Posts by Scribu`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) which is not maintained currently, but It's bug-less and won't introduce any problems in a long shot. But please be aware that this plugin requires some coding to get it up and ready and has to be active to work.
2. **Coding it yourself**

   I'm not against the above plugin but, If you're not going to have only one relationship of this type then, I highly recommend you to develop a basic `many-to-many` relationship for it. The only reason for this is the age of plugin and its small community.

Comment: To suggest an outdated/unmaintained plugin is not a good idea in my opinion. [ACF offers various relational fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) and custom implementation isn't too difficult. Just save an array of `gear_children` in the Photographer's `postmeta` and an array of `photographer_parent` in the Gear's `postmeta`

Comment: Yes, I'm completely against of using this plugin but, It's a quick workaround and by reading the ACF docs and forum they know this issue exists and they provided a workaround which consists of a data duplication.
You can read more at: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/bidirectional-relationships/